# First python app on C9 with error

Tags: python

after doing the courses of python and reading some books i decided to do an app. Since that seemed overwhelming I researched and found this http://sebsauvage.net/python/gui/ which im replicating on Cloud9.io, and got here:

```
import Tkinter
class simpleapp_tk(Tkinter.Tk):
      def __init__(self,parent):
        Tkinter.Tk.__init__(self,parent)
        self.parent = parent
        self.initialize()

    def initialize(self):
        pass

if __name__== '__main__':
    app = simpleapp_tk(None)
    app.title('FirstApp')
    app.mainloop()
```

All well and fine, but now they say we can run it and see a empty window, which when i run gives me this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ubuntu/workspace/Calculator/Calc.py", line 22, in <module>
    app().mainloop()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk/Tkinter.py", line 2537, in __init__
    Widget.__init__(self, master, 'frame', cnf, {}, extra)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk/Tkinter.py", line 2049, in __init__
    BaseWidget._setup(self, master, cnf)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk/Tkinter.py", line 2024, in _setup
    _default_root = Tk()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk/Tkinter.py", line 1767, in __init__
    self.tk = _tkinter.create(screenName, baseName, className, interactive, wantobjects, useTk, sync, use)
_tkinter.TclError: no display name and no $DISPLAY environment variable


Process exited with code: 1
```

Any ideas on what's wrong or how to fix it? thanks

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to run a GUI app on Cloud9, which has no desktop environment. You'll want to look into web frameworks if you're going to run on a cloud provider.

Flask is a good, simple one.

Alternatively, if you like books and you're interested in Django, you might check out [Hello Web App](https://hellowebapp.com/).

Answer (score 0):

UNIX like systems connects to an X server (display server) to draw, using the info in the `DISPLAY` variable, and it is not set.

Cloud9 doesn't support X forwarding (forwarding to a remote X server) either, so no GUI apps there, only web apps.